# Free abelian group for the cartesian product

Tags: category-theory

Is there any way to show $\mathbb{Z}\{A\times B\} \cong \mathbb{Z}\{A\}\otimes \mathbb{Z}\{B\}$ using adjoint functors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a set $B$ and let $F_1(A)=\mathbb{Z}\{A\times B\}$ and $F_2(A)=\mathbb{Z}\{A\}\otimes \mathbb{Z}\{B\}$.  Both of these are functors $Set\to Ab$ and are manifestly a composition of two left adjoints: $F_1$ is the composition of $A\mapsto A\times B$ and the free functor, while $F_2$ is the composition of the free functor and $C\mapsto C\otimes \mathbb{Z}\{B\}$.  Thus $F_1$ and $F_2$ have right adjoints, which can be computed as the composition of the right adjoints of the functors they are composed of.  The right adjoint $G_1$ of $F_1$ is the composition of the forgetful functor $Ab\to Set$ and the functor $C\mapsto C^B$; that is, $G_1(C)$ is the set of functions from $B$ to the underlying set of $C$.  The right adjoint $G_2$ of $F_2$ is the composition of the functor $C\mapsto \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}\{B\},C)$ with the forgetful functor; that is, $G_2(C)$ is the set of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}\{B\}$ to $C$.

By definition of $\mathbb{Z}\{B\}$, the functors $G_1$ and $G_2$ are naturally isomorphic.  It follows that their left adjoints $F_1$ and $F_2$ are also naturally isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Both sides are cocontinuous functors in $A$ and $B$ separately because they are compositions of cocontinuous functors in $A$ and $B$ separately (even left adjoints). A functor out of $\text{Set} \times \text{Set}$ cocontinuous in each variable is completely determined by what it does to $(1, 1)$, because every set is a colimit of copies of $1$. And both sides have the same value, namely $\mathbb{Z}$, on $(1, 1)$.